# socket.io - works first time, not second time onwards

Tags: node.js, websocket, express, socket.io

When I start my node.js server and client gets connected, I am able to send a request from client (socket.emit) and get a response (socket.on('rentsAround'....)). But when I connect 2nd time onwards, the client is able to send, but server can not send or emit. So I have to restart the server again. I understand that it is working as expected, but somehow my understanding is wrong somewhere... Would someone please point out.

**client side:
========**

```
    var socket = new io.Socket();
    socket = io.connect();

    socket.on('rentsAround', function(data){
        registration.handleRentsAround(data);
    });


    socket.on('locationDetailsRes', function(data){
        registration.handleRentsAround(data);
    });

    socket.on('connect', function(data){
        alert('inside connect on client side');
    });

socket.on('disconnect', function(){ 
    // do something, if you want to. 
    });
    .............
    socket.emit("searchRent",  {"lat":lat, "lng":lng});
```

**server side:
========**

```
socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client){ 

            client.on('searchRent', function(msg){
        console.log('inside on connection');
                // do something and reply back
        client.emit('rentsAround',{"totalRents":docs.length, "rents":docs});
            });

   client.on('disconnect', function(){ 
        sys.puts("client disconnect"); 
        mongoose.disconnect();
        });
```

Comment: I haven't really dabbled with sockets.io but from what I can tell, you aren't closing the connection & your listening to the connection event. In theory, wouldn't your first connection cause the server to respond & subsequent messages wouldn't actually hit that event?

Comment: i am sorry for not providing the complete code. but I do have disconnect both in client and server side.. updating the code in question..

Comment: got the problem while replying to your queries. Actually the socket code is just fine.. while disconnecting in the server side, I was disconnecting the database connection also and that created the problem. Thanks for your pointer !!

Comment: I can't answer your question definitively because you haven't included the second call to `connect`. If you need to, post more code on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/) or an equivalent site and include a link in your question.

Answer (score 34):

Socket.io 0.7 onwards will try and reuse connections to the same host. In my experience I've found this behaviour can be a little flakey.

I can't tell from the small code sample you provided, but I *suspect* the problem is that the second call to `connect()` is trying to reuse the first (closed) connection.

The workaround is to pass the `'force new connection'` option when you call `connect()`. Eg:

`io.connect("http://localhost", {'force new connection': true});`

Comment: Thanks for 'force new connection'... I did not know about this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my life ;) I hate those nodejs/socket.io guys with their updates. I almost never managed to update without something falling apart. I developed on 0.6 and recently updated the production server. And got complaints from clients that it is "not working". Generally it is not that easy to test everything properly, and changes like this don't make it any better.

Comment: can someone please mark this as the best answer since OP said it worked?

Comment: fyi, there is an annoying side effect to this work around. If you are using name spacing on your socket connections io.connect('/mySocket1') and io.connect('/mySocket2'), using 'force new connection' will cause them not to share a connection as they do by default; so, while it will allow you to reconnect the two lost connections after a forced disconnect when you reconnect them, they will each have their own connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line discards the object created in the first line. Simply doing this should work:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

The problem with first send and second fail could be due to browser/protocol. I have seen such behaviour with Internet Explorer and XHR transport, and also with Opera using JSONP.

If you are using IE, try switching to JSONP and it should work properly. This can be done on the server side, by supplying the transport list to configuration. Just make sure JSONP comes before XHR. Something like this:

```
sio.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
    , 'flashsocket'
    , 'jsonp-polling'
    , 'xhr-polling'
    , 'htmlfile'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of socket.io 1.0, two settings control this behaviour:

- `"force new connection":true`, on the client connect() call.
- `"cookie":false`, on the server Server() constructor.

Apparently, both produce the exact same behaviour.

The second method is, as of today, undocumented. However, looking at the source code you can see that all options passed to socket.io Server() are passed to the internal Engine.io library Server() constructor, which lets you change any of the options there. These options are documented here:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io